# Have an error when creating inner product layer with caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, inner-product

> ```
> E0426 16:55:44.986892  4273 io.cpp:80] Could not open or find file 
> F0426 16:55:45.023268  4273 image_data_layer.cpp:129] Check failed: cv_img.data Could not load 
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
> @     0x7f2f16c335cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
> @     0x7f2f16c35433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
> @     0x7f2f16c3315b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
> @     0x7f2f16c35e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
> @     0x7f2f1714491d  caffe::ImageDataLayer<>::load_batch()
> @     0x7f2f171470fa  caffe::BasePrefetchingDataLayer<>::InternalThreadEntry()
> @     0x7f2f16fbfe7e  boost::detail::thread_data<>::run()
> @     0x7f2f143455d5  (unknown)
> @     0x7f2f13bf36fa  start_thread
> @     0x7f2f15c8ab5d  clone
> @              (nil)  (unknown)
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message you got:

> ```
> F0426 16:55:45.023268  4273 image_data_layer.cpp:129] Check failed: cv_img.data Could not load
> ```

First of all, the error comes from [`'image_data_layer.cpp:129'`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp#L129), that is, line 129 in `$CAFFE_ROOT/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp` line 129. Check this line out. What you'll see is that this error happens when caffe cannot load an input image file provided by an `"ImageData"` layer.
Check that all your input images exists and the files are not corrupted.

**This error has nothing to do with `"InnerProduct"` layer**.